# How does ViewBag get passed to ViewContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

below is some source code:

```
public abstract class RazorPageBase : IRazorPage
{
   // ...
   public dynamic ViewBag => ViewContext.ViewBag;
   
}

public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IFilterMetadata, IAsyncActionFilter, IDisposable
{
   // ...
   public dynamic ViewBag 
   {
      get {
         if (_viewBag == null)
            _viewBag = new DynamicViewData(() => ViewData);
         
         return _viewBag;
      }
   }


   [NonAction]
   public virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, object model)   
   {
      ViewData.Model = model;

      return new ViewResult()
      {
         ViewName = viewName,
         ViewData = ViewData,
         TempData = TempData
      };
   }
   // ...
}
```

So somehow the ViewBag is passed from the `Controller` to the `ViewContext`, then I track the source code down to the part that create the `ViewContext` https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewExecutor.cs,186

```
public class ViewExecutor
{
   

   public virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, int statusCode) 
   {
      var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, view, viewData, tempData, 
                                        TextWriter.Null, ViewOptions.HtmlHelperOptions);  
      // ...     
   }
}
```

still doesn't set the ViewBag property on the `ViewContext` instance, so how does the ViewBag from controller get passed to ViewContext's ViewBag  property? which class does this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag and ViewData shares the same container

You could try as below in controller:

```
ViewBag.Bagmsg = "ViewBagMessage";
ViewData["Datamsg"] = "ViewDataMessage";
```

When you debug:

[image]

and you could check this class:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/DynamicViewData.cs